# Sequence contains more than one matching element codefirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting this error when trying to update relationship (one to one)
with fluent api this are my classes :

```
    public class Organisation
{
    [Key]
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }

    public string organisationName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; internal set; }
    public string LastName { get; internal set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public int? OrganisationDetalisId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrganisationDetalis OrDetalis { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Aeroa> aeroa { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> orders { get; set; }

}
  public class OrganisationDetalis
    {
        [Key]
        public int OrganisationDetalisId { get; set; }
        //remove for clear code
        public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
        public virtual Organisation organisation { get; set; }
    }
    public DbSet<Organisation> organisation { get; set; }
       public DbSet<OrganisationDetalis> OrDetalis { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrganisationDetalis>()
            .HasKey(o => o.OrganisationId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Organisation>()
            .HasOptional(ad => ad.OrDetalis).WithRequired(oo => oo.organisation);
    }
```

but I keep getting that error when updating view nugget console 
where is the problem?

Comment: So, what error do you have? Is it initial data migration?

Comment: after adding the fluent api  as up , I cant get any data from my db tables :
Sequence contains more than one matching element 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review... 
 Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
Source Error: 
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
:         {
            var aeroa = db.aeroa.Include(a => a.Languages);
:             return View(await aeroa.ToListAsync());
         }

Comment: Solve . I need to delete the migration files.